Java internal compiler error when using custom annotation processor
I'm developing a custom annotation processor in Spring Boot. Initially, annotation processor just doesn't execute, but during the second or third compilation, I get java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error, and the code is not compiling even if I remove everything I added since the error began to appear.
I use Java version 17 and Spring Boot 2.7.8. Code below:
Annotation Processor
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.storely.server.statistics.AnalyzeData"})
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class AnalyzeDataAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return false;
    }

}

Annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AnalyzeData {
}

I have used my annotation on one test class only, but it hasn't worked yet.
I have tried deleting modified files, but the compilation remains failing. Also, before the compiler error started occurring, the annotation processor didn't work, which I tested with sout.
I get different erros for different compilers:
Javac:
java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
Eclipse:
Module 'server' production: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.storely.server.statistics.AnalyzeDataAnnotationProcessor not found
Groovy-Eclipse:
Groovy-Eclipse: Invalid jar path in the compiler settings: '

Could mean a number of things, are you getting anymore logs that you can attach here to help debug the problem ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
